# How to find the number of swaps in bubble sort if the list is a range

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, bubble-sort

I want to find the number of swaps (not comparisons) needed to sort an array of length N using bubble sort, when the array contains all numbers from 0 to N-1.
I wondered if you could, instead of actually simulating the sort, speed up the process thanks to the fact that for every number you a) know in what position it would end up being (the same as the value of the number) and b) know exactly how many numbers are greater and lesser than it.

I made a simple function to calculate it but the complexity is `O(N^2)` and that's too high.

C++

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < len; j++) {
        if(arr[j] < arr[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/idea is appreciated.

Comment: So even though you know exactly which numbers are in the array, their order is random?

Comment: *"and that's too high"* - What does "too high" mean? What would be *not* too high?

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing about a bubble sort is that every swap moves an item exactly one position. Since you know the starting and ending positions, a simple subtraction can tell you how many swaps it will take to get to its final resting place. Unfortunately each swap will move *two* items at the same time, and it's possible for an item to shortcut some swaps or overshoot the final location. So you can't rely on that.

I don't see a way to count other than performing the actual sort.

Comment: For a moment I was worried you were going to say "so divide the sum of differences by 2" :-). Your last paragraph doesn't make sense, though, since the question already shows a way that doesn't perform the actual sort.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes the question contains a solution, but is it accurate? I'm not convinced it is. I suppose it wouldn't be too much trouble to try it and see.

Comment: Yes it is. It just counts the number of inversions, which is exactly the number of swaps that bubble sort does (since each swap reduces the number of inversions by exactly 1, and the final sorted state has no inversions).

Comment: Ways to count the inversions in O(n log n) time are also rather well-known, but I don't know whether the input being such a "range" allows something even better (otherwise I might've duplicate-voted it already). It's something I've thought about before but never found an answer to...

Comment: @KellyBundy I did my test and verified the solution in the question.  But it's O(n^2) just like the sort itself, right?  So nothing gained.

Comment: Yes, as the question also said, and which is why they're asking.